# Add line when end of the window is reached using curses?

Tags: curses

I have a small repl app using curses but I'm facing a problem to add new lines when end of window is reach. Output looks like the following, being `---` the window limits:

```
---
REPL> :dothis
====>  Well done!
REPL> :dothat
====>  OK, done
REPL> :dothatagain====>  All right...REPL> // can't add more lines :(
---
```

How do I `addstr` when end of window is reached just like a normal terminal buffer? I don't need to scroll back, just write a trail of lines. Is there any window setting to get an infinite vertical window?

Answers in any common language are fine (C preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research on curses native API I noticed there is a `int scrollok(WINDOW *win, bool bf);` function:

```
scrollok(*window, true);
```

I didn't find the function before because the curses biding library I was using didn't have this function implemented so I just made a wrapper for it. Conclusion is to always look at the native curses API when using external language API bidings.